# Class instance can't see a function it refers to

Tags: python, class, import, module, nameerror

I have this module containing a class definition and instantiation, like so:

```
class TestClass:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
    def func(self, count):
        count = test_func(count)
        return count

my_inst = TestClass('my_inst')
```

Note that *TestClass.func* refers to a function (*test_func*) that is not in the module. Then, I open a notebook where that function is defined and import the *TestClass* and its instance, *my_inst*. The *count* variable is also defined in the notebook, so the code in it looks as follows:

```
from test_module import *

count = 0

def test_func(count):
    count += 1
    return count
```

Then, I try to run the *my_inst.func(count)* method...

```
for _ in range(10):
    count = my_inst.func(count)
```

...and get a NameError: name 'test_func' is not defined.

What seems to be the problem here? Why doesn't the class instance see the *test_func* in the notebook? How can I make it see it?

Comment: Are you aware of the [scoping rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291978/short-description-of-the-scoping-rules)? Python is *lexically* scoped, functions only see what is in their *defining* scope not their *using* scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to import `test_func` within the file in which `TestClass` is defined. You're doing the opposite (i.e., you're importing `TestClass` within the file in which `test_func` is defined), which is wrong and will never work.

File `test_function.py`:

```
count = 0

def test_func(count):
    count += 1
    return count
```

File `test_class.py`:

```
from test_function import test_func

class TestClass:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
    def func(self, count):
        count = test_func(count)
        return count

my_inst = TestClass('my_inst')
```

Now you can import everything you need in your notebook.